# Patch authentication program with gcc modification

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

My problem is that with the newer versions of gcc the security leak for the following little authentication program cannot be fixed.

The following program should only output "Access garanted" if the right password gets typed, but with a buffer overflow it´s possible to "hack" this program.

Program (raw):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_auth(char *passwd){
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char passwd_buffer[16];
    strcpy(passwd_buffer, passwd);
    if(strcmp(passwd_buffer, "brillig") == 0){
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    if(strcmp(passwd_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0){
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_auth(argv[1])){
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
        printf("Access garanted!\n");
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
    }else{
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
        printf("Access denied!\n");
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ gcc auth_buffer_overflow.c 
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out "outgrabe"
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out "brillig"
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
```

So I know that this is only possible because of the buffer overflow and the resulting overwrite of the next variable in the stack. And in my case this variable is the "auth_flag" variable and since the value of this variable isn´t equals to 0 the condition for executing the if-statement in the main() function is given. Therefore I tried to manipulate the stack so that the "auth_flag" cannot be overwritten anymore.

Program (tried to fix the issue):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_auth(char *passwd){
    char passwd_buffer[16];
    int auth_flag = 0;
    strcpy(passwd_buffer, passwd);
    if(strcmp(passwd_buffer, "brillig") == 0){
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    if(strcmp(passwd_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0){
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_auth(argv[1])){
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
        printf("Access garanted!\n");
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
    }else{
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
        printf("Access denied!\n");
        printf("=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=\n");
    }
}
```

After compiling the output was:

```
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out "brillig"
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out "outgrabe"
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
[w4r10ck@localhost Hacking_with_C]$ ./a.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
Access garanted!
=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=_=
```

So obviously the modification didn`t work. But I` ve read that this is because newer gcc versions don`t arrange the variables like in the order given from the program but rather like is wants to.
Is there any possibility to modify gcc that is works like older versions?

Comment: So _don't_ let the buffer overflow. You should check the length of the input password and if it is too long reject it: `if(strlen(argv[1])>15) ...`

Comment: I know that thanks but what I want to know is how to do this with gcc only.

Comment: Why copy the string at all here?

Comment: @Hasturkun may be the provided code is a *Minimal, Reproducible Example* (as encouraged) and the real applicative context requires this copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is very unsecure with a `passwd` string that could have any length.

```
strcpy(passwd_buffer, passwd);
```

Why not use this?

```
strncpy(passwd_buffer, passwd, sizeof(passwd_buffer)-1);
passwd_buffer[sizeof(passwd_buffer)-1]='\0';
```

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

---

Aside from this particular problem of overflow, variables are just an abstraction to name the values in an algorithm in order to help the programmers elaborate a reasonning.
A soon as an optimizing compiler is used the variables *may not even exist*.
It's hard to figure this out because when asking for an *unoptimised* build in order to use a debugger, we actually ask the compiler to make the variable exist in order to observe them in the debugger.
But the optimised code is very different from the unoptimised one.
Even in unoptimised mode, nothing in the standard of the language specifies how the variables should be laid out.
A compiler could choose a layout different from another one.

Comment: I guess you mean `strncpy(passwd_buffer, passwd, sizeof(password_buffer)-1);` right?

Comment: @Kry9t0n yes, I made some typos and mistakes in the initial post, but edited since. sorry about that

Comment: @Kry9t0n I just edited about your question concerning the place were the variables actually are.

Comment: So if I get this right in theory it would be possible but the resulting code wouldn´t be so optimized as with the newer versions of gcc, right?

Comment: @Kry9t0n I am not sure about that because, even in *unoptimised* mode, nothing in the standard of the language specifies how the variables should be laid out. A compiler could choose a solution different from another one.

Comment: Upvoted for the good practice advice. Even if strncpy will put the zero termination in most cases, when the string is too long and then truncated strncpy will not write the zero termination, so it's important to write it explicitly after the call.